# How do I print the number of items with 'for loops' in a list and dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

How do I print the number of items with 'for loops' in a list and dictionary?
Here's my code:

```
for key, val in i.items():

    print(key, val)

q = ["Quests: ", "Look at inventory, ", "Press 'r' or 'l'."]

for x in q:

    print(x)
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I can't print the # of items in my dictionary(which is 'i') or the # of items in my list(which is 'q')

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean "number of items with for loops in a list and dictionary"? You don't need a loop at all to do this. What does your dictionary look like? Do you want to print the number of keys in the dict? Where is the list you for which you want to find the number of items? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre] that reproduces your problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand but try that:

```
len(i)
```

This equals the length of dictionary 'i'.
AKA number of items in it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Printing the number of items in the dictionary:

`print(len(i.keys()))`

Printing the number of items in the list:

`print(len(q))`

Not sure why you'd need a `for` loop though.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are new to Python, since most tutorials on Python cover this basic concept pretty quickly.

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying something like:

```
for i in range(len(a_list)):
    print(i)
```

You could then also access each item of a list with: `a_list[i]`

Note that this will not work the same way with a dictionary. `a_dictionary[i]` would not get the `i`th element. It would instead look for a key with the value `i`.

I'd suggest you follow one of the many helpful tutorials online.

Answer (score -1):

There's two ways. The simplest is to use the length function len(). len(yourList) and len(yourDictionary) will give their sizes, aka the number of items in them.

However to do this manually, in case you iterate only part of a list you just create a counter variable.
so

```
counter = 0

for key, value in i.items():
    print(key, value)
    counter += 1

print(counter)
```